# pandas dataframe column name: remove special character

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, special-characters

Some joker made a Lotus database/applet thingy for tracking engineering issues in our company.  The joke is that the key piece of information was named with a special character... a number sign (hash tag, pound sign, \u0023).

abbreviated sample:

```
KA#         Issue Date      Current Position
27144       1/9/2014        Accounting
27194       12/20/2012      Engineering
32474       4/21/2008       Engineering
32623-HOLD  4/25/2016       Engineering
32745       11/13/2012      SEPE
32812       10/30/2013      Engineering
32817       12/7/2012       Purchasing
32839       1/8/2013        SEPE
```

I output this table (4K rows, 15 columns) to a csv file and process in python3 as a pandas dataframe.

I generate various outputs.  If I use something like:

```
df.iloc[:,[0,3,1,8,9,10]]
```

I get appropriate output and the key column shows up as `"KA#"`. (When I say "key column", I mean "most important"... NOT "index".  I keep a serial index)

Unfortunately, people sometimes mess with the column order in Lotus between my exports to csv so I can not guarantee that `"KA#"` will be any particular column number.  I would like to use column names:

```
df.loc[:,["KA#","Issue Date","Current Position"]]
```

But the `"KA#"` column is filled with NaN's.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Finally, if I try to rename `"KA#"` to simply `"KA"`:

```
df['KA#'].name = 'KA'
```

throws a KeyError and

```
df = df.rename(columns={"KA#": "ka"})
```

is completely ignored.  The column shows up as `"KA#"`.

Can anyone think of a way to get rid of or handle that symbol?  I'd even settle for a regex at this point.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

use [str.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace):
`df.columns=df.columns.str.replace('#','')`

You can check this in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html).

Comment: And in particular, assign this result back to `df.columns`.

Comment: This took care of my problem because I only had one column with an improper character and I wanted it gone.  Hence, "answered". and "thank you" to shivsn.

If I wanted to target a particular column, then this would be a rather clumsy methodology.  I think I'll worry about that one when I get to it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead we can use lambda functions for removing special characters in the column like:

```
df2 = df1.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('*'))
```