# Pushing pandas dataframe with special characters (dot “.”) in column name to mssql using sqlalchemy and pure python (without pyodbc dependency)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Below command to save pandas dataframe that contains special character (dot - “.”) works fine using “pyodbc” library but throws following error while trying to push data into sql using pure python ([sqlalchemy and pytds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51947862/5096369))

```
df = pd.DataFrame({‘name.display':‘display value’, ‘name.value':‘John'})
df.to_sql('users', con=engine, if_exists=‘replace')
```

Error: 
*sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pytds.tds_base.OperationalError) Incorrect sytax near ‘.’ Must declare scalar variable “@user”*

I already tried…

1. wrapping column names with square brackets but it seems it’s already done by pandas when data are being pushed into database and ends up creating double brackets around column name and fails at table creation
2. tried [renaming column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952797/pandas-dataframe-column-name-remove-special-character) names (replace  “.” to “_”) that works but we have a requirement that need dot in the column naming convention across multiple database tables

Looking for pure python approach since our linux environment doesn’t have odbc support

wanted to check with python community for any suggestions, thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried `mssql+pymssql`?

Comment: couldn’t figure out creating connection with cafile to enable TLS/SSL encryption using pymssql (pytds.connect does support cafile parameter to enable TLS/SSL) and also pymssql is being discontinued
https://python-tds.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pytds.html#pytds.Cursor.connectio

Comment: Hmm, so if pyodbc works but you can't use it, and pymssql won't work because of encryption, then you may need to create a [sqlalchemy-tds issue](https://github.com/m32/sqlalchemy-tds/issues) and see if they can help you out.

Comment: Another thing you might try of to explicitly specify `schema="dbo"` (or whatever it is) in your `to_sql` call.

Comment: Tried that as well (schema ="dbo") results in same error