# Remove all special characters in all column names / headers in pandas / python

Tags: python, pandas

There is a pretty similar question on this page: [pandas dataframe column name: remove special character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952797/pandas-dataframe-column-name-remove-special-character)

but in my case, I have several special characters in the column names / headers, so the example is with a pandas dataframe df:

```
('Untitled 1, Year')       ('Untitled 1', 'Name')       ('Life', 'Age')
2000                            John                       24
2001                            Kelly                      32
```

How can I remover all the special characters from the column headers? I am searching for a way, that I don't have to use the replace method several times for every special character. That the output looks like this:

```
Untitled 1 Year            Untitled 1 Name                Life Age
2000                            John                       24
2001                            Kelly                      32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pdb
import pandas as pd 
import re 

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["('Untitled 1, Year')", "('Untitled 1', 'Name')", "('Life', 'Age')"])

df.rename(columns=lambda c: re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', c), inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do this. This solution first build a translation table using `str.maketrans` and then replace each character in the string using that translation table(`str.translate`)

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> 
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import string
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "('Untitled 1, Year')": [1, 2],
...         "('Untitled 1', 'Name')": [2, 3],
...         "('Life', 'Age')": [5, 5],
...     }
... )
>>> 
>>> character_to_replace = "(,)'"
>>> replacement = ""
>>> table = str.maketrans({char: replacement for char in character_to_replace})
>>> 
>>> df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.translate(table))
>>> 
>>> print(df)
   Untitled 1 Year  Untitled 1 Name  Life Age
0                1                2         5
1                2                3         5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
### This will remove all the special characters from the text
def replace_special_chars_with_space(text):
    chars_to_replace = "~!@#$%^&*()_+"
    for char in chars_to_replace:
        text = text.replace(char, " ")
    return text
    
### Reasign column names    
df.columns = [replace_special_chars_with_space(col) for col in df.columns ]
```